# Docker: efficiently migrate image to another registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I need to migrate many Docker images from an old registry to a new one. The standard way to do this would be:

```
docker pull old-registry/image:tag
docker tag old-registry/image:tag new-registry/image:tag
docker push new-registry/image:tag
docker rmi old-registry/image:tag
docker rmi new-registry/image:tag
```

Now some of these images are really huge, beyond 100GB, and the entire procedure takes really long. Can anyone think of a way to speed it up? Is there something like a direct transfer between registries? Or, at least, is there a possibility to avoid the "extraction phase" on the `docker pull` command. Because the extracting here takes much longer than pulling, and I don't actually need it to be extracted.